# Created Pushed Animation for BarButton

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

On a view controller, I have a back button with custom image via this code

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left207.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToParent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

But when I run the app, there is no pushed sort of effect. It doesn't turn dark for a second.

Comment: You have only set one image. Use a different image for UIControlStateSelected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set another image for highlighted state:

```
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedButton"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```